# How to set multiple certificate for a .NET TcpListener as a Server?

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, https, listener

I see only one certificate can be assigned to a listener.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream?view=netcore-3.1

```
sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(serverCertificate, clientCertificateRequired: false, checkCertificateRevocation: true);
```

How can I set multiple certificates on a listener so I can host more than one client on a single ip?

Comment: I believe you need SAN or wildcard cert...

Comment: `SslStream` is not a listener, but represents a single connection - how would you like to determine which certificate to use for any given connection?

Comment: @C.Evenhuis I knew, we initial the listener by TcpListener. I can see IIS can manage that. I think SslStream should accept multiple certificates and have a property that indicate which certificate is requested by the client and validated by AuthenticateAsServer. in that case we can determine the connection. I hope I don't need to rewrite all AuthenticateAsServer again.

Comment: IIS uses Http.sys to handle incoming HTTPS connections, and that’s why it can use different certificates for different connections. However, your code relies on a completely different design, so it won’t support the same.

Comment: A typical web server would accept a TCP connection, select a certificate to authenticate with and _then_ receive the HTTP request over that secure connection. Since the HTTP request contains the host header, there would be no way to select a certificate based on that header. But as always I'm a few steps behind. Alexei Levenkov already mentioned two of the tree possible solutions mentioned at https://serverfault.com/questions/126072/ssl-certificate-selection-based-on-host-header-is-it-possible

Comment: @C.Evenhuis SSL establish a connection from client by sending a special unencrypted Hello packet that contains SNI (Server Name Indicator) over TCP before sending HTTP headers packets which indicate the domain and certificate. AuthenticateAsServer actually process that but unfortunately it looks C# TcpListener doesn't support handling multiple certificate at server or maybe I miss something!

Comment: So would you be able to use the `SslStream` constructor with the overload that takes a `LocalCertificateSelectionCallback`? In that callback the requested hostname is provided and you can return the corresponding certificate. Again I haven't dealt with SNI before but just curious.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis Unfortunately SslStream doesn't work like that! LocalCertificateSelectionCallback is for something else.